# Read an Array of Arrays separated by blank lines in Julia

Tags: arrays, sorting, julia

I have an array of arrays stored as blocks of tabular data in a textfile. The blocks have different number of rows but the same number of columns. Like this:

```
7 9
9 9

7 1
1 1
3 3

4 1
```

And so on.
I would like to read them in Julia and to end with an array of arrays, or an array of 2 dimensional arrays, like this:

```
a=[ [7, 9; 9 ,9], [7, 1; 1, 1 ; 3 3 ]] ...
```

I am trying with different ideas with **do** syntax, but I am being not very succesfull yet.

```
aux=[]
open("cell.dat") do f
    aux=[]
    aux2=[]
    for line in eachline(f)
        if line != ""
            aux2=vcat(aux2,line)
        else
            print("tuabuela")
            aux=vcat(aux,aux2)
            print(aux, aux2)
            aux2=[]
        end
    end
end
```

I end with an empty array!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Suppose the file is not huge and you have read your file to `String` called `dat`:

```
dat="""7 9     
9 9            
               
7 1            
1 1            
3 3            
               
4 1"""
```

In that case you can do:

```
julia> readdlm.(IOBuffer.(split(dat,"\n\n")))
3-element Vector{Matrix{Float64}}:
 [7.0 9.0; 9.0 9.0]
 [7.0 1.0; 1.0 1.0; 3.0 3.0]
 [4.0 1.0]
```

Comment: I got this weird error:
at row 0, column 0 : ArgumentError("number of rows in dims must be > 0, got 0")

Comment: @wpkzz Are the blocks separated by exactly one blank line every time? If not, try replacing `"\n\n"` with `r"\n{2,}"` in the `split` call. Also, make sure the file doesn't end with a blank line at the end (this to me seems the most likely source of the error). If neither of these solve it, please update the question with the full stacktrace of the error you're getting.

Comment: Try replacing `dat` with `strip(dat)` - in that way you will remove empty lines at the beginning and end of the text.